# "Please indicate a target file in the refile path" when trying to refile in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Trying to refile in a very simple org-mode buffer:

```
* H1
** Sub a
** Sub b
* H2
** Sub c
```

I put point on Sub b, hit `C-c C-w` and choose H2 as the target. I then get the message "Please indicate a target file in the refile path" and am unable to proceed.  Very confused.  Have tried having started with `emacs -q` and have not changed anything through Customise, so I don't think it is anything in my customisations.  Hoping for guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to save the buffer to a file before you can refile.